# A little help on a mod_rewrite expression

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a very quick fix in a mod_rewrite expression for drupal we have

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$ 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But i need to redirect the value of the subdomain in get too so i need something that will give:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$ 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?subdomain=THE SUBDOMAIN HERE&q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Don't know how to do it, please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying this again, for some reason my code isn't rendering properly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?subdomain=%1&q=1 [L,QSA]
```

Based off of some forum posts I found [here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=33868).

Comment: Note that if the domain is www.foo.domain.com subdomain will be passed www.foo

Comment: I would DRY up the REQUEST_URI condition: !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php)$

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the subdomain in the query string.

The subdomain can be found in PHP in $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].

[PHP documentation](http://no.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says:

```
'SERVER_NAME'
    The name of the server host under which the
    current script is executing. If the script
    is running on a virtual host, this will be
    the value defined for that virtual host.
```